# How to send variable with the guzzle post method

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have an API and I need to send some data to it and I am using guzzle for handling it so here is my code:

```
$amount = $request->get('amount');
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $requestapi = $client->post('http://192.168.150.16:7585/api/v1/Transaction/GetTransactionNumber', [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => '{
        "Amount":"i want to send $amount here",
        "something":"1",
        "Description":"desc",
        }'
    ]);
```

so every thing is fine and static data is being send but I want to know how can I send a variable.

Comment: you can use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert array to json and assign it to variable and use it. what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amount can pass in an array and after you can encode with json using ```json_encode``

Hope this works for you.

```
$amount = $request->get('amount');
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url   = "http://192.168.150.16:7585/api/v1/Transaction/GetTransactionNumber";
$data   = [
            "amount"      => $amount,
            "something"   => "1",
            "description" => "desc",
          ];

$requestAPI = $client->post( $url, [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => json_encode($data);
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the data in form_params parameter like

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$amount = $request->get('amount');
$requestapi = $client->post('http://192.168.150.16:7585/api/v1/Transaction/GetTransactionNumber', [
                   'form_params' => [
                        "Amount" => "i want to send $amount here",
                        "something" => "1",
                        "Description" => "desc",
                   ]
             ]);
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Guzzle **json** option:

```
$amount = $request->get('amount');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post(
    'http://192.168.150.16:7585/api/v1/Transaction/GetTransactionNumber', 
    [
        GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
            'Amount' => $amount,
            'something' => '1',
            'Description' => 'desc',
        ]
    ]
);
```

Check Guzzle manual - http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json